# Выравнивание ячейки таблицы по высоте

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая таблица:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="15"></td>
                    <td><button type="button"></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

`Content` - некое текстовое содержимое, переменной длины. В случае, если он не влазит на одну строку, то захватывает следующую. В этом случае  `checkbox` и `button` зависнут на уровне первой строки.

Пробовал добавлять в стиль table следующее:

```
display: table-cell;         
vertical-align: middle;
```

а также:

```
align-items: center
```

Не помогло.

Как выровнять по высоте остальные колонки, которым всегда будет хватать места на одной строке?

Comment: `table td { vertical-align: middle; }` – нужно не таблице задавать, а ячейке

Comment: @Artem_Gorlachev И table задавал, и tr задавал, а нужно каждой td прописывать. Спасибо, работает. Может быть, вы оформите отдельно, а я отмечу как правильный ответ?